# Tight sets w.r.t. Hall's condition

Tags: bipartite-matching

Consider a bipartite graph G=(U+V,E) and suppose |U|=|V| and that G has a perfect matching. Therefore by P. Hall's condition, for every subsets A of U, the neighborhood N(A) of A has size at least |A|.
I am interested in subsets A for which N(A) has the same cardinality as A. Do they have a name?

It seems that any perfect matching must contain a sub-matching between A and N(A).
Is there an algorithm to identify the largest proper subset of U that has this property?

Comment: These sets are sometimes known as *critical sets*. If $|U| = |V|$, then $U$ itself is a critical set. If $|U| < |V|$, then a critical set need not exist – consider for example the complete bipartite graph.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed considering the largest critical set does not make sense if the two sides have the same cardinality (which is what I had in mind). 
So, I guess, I am looking for the largest critical proper subset.

Comment: It doesn’t necessarily exist. Consider a complete bipartite graph.

Comment: Indeed. It doesn't have to. I am looking for an algorithm that finds one, in case it exists.

Comment: If you want to find any proper set satisfying $|A| = |N(A)|$, just go over all ways of removing one vertex for each side, and look for a *Hall violator*.

Comment: You might be able to combine this idea (removing vertices) with some version of max-flow-min-cut.